# How to change the key password from an PKCS12 keystore

Tags: certificate, keytool, pkcs#12

I am trying to change the password of a certificate stored in an p12 keystore. I managed to change the keystore password by using the ikeycmd, but for the keypass nothing seems to work. This is the command I was trying:

keytool -keypasswd -storetype PKCS12 -keystore $KEYSTORE_FILE -alias $KEY_ALIAS -keypass $KEY_PASSWORD -new $new_pass -storepass $store_pass

and I am receiving the following output:
keytool error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: -keypasswd commands not supported if -storetype is PKCS12

I tried to run the command without the -storetype PKCS12 option and I got:
keytool error (likely untranslated): java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Can anyone, please, help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As per the internet standard, these are things you should follow when creating/dealing with a `PCKS12` keystore:

1. The `PKCS12` should contain only 1 keypair entry, i.e., a private key associated with a certificate chain.
2. The key password of the only entry is the same as the keystore password.

Java follows these rules too. So that's why the error when you try to change the key password when you provide the store type as PKCS12.

So ideally you are only supposed to change the keystore password for a PKCS12 keystore. You shouldn't be changing the key password.

But if the pkcs12 keystore doesn't follow the above rules, and you are trying to correct it, and unsuccessful to do so by using java `keytool` command, I recommend trying to fix it using [keystore-explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) (a GUI tool to interact with any keystore).

It has an option to change the key password of the entry.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: "As per the internet standard". What standard?

Comment: @peterh this ones: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS . Cryptography more than Internet, but still...

Comment: @RobM. How does that link explain what this answer says is an internet standard?  (that there's only one keypair entry in the file and that the password for this entry is the same as for the file as a whole). I certainly agree that it seems to be a widely used _convention_, but I haven't found anywhere where this is stated.

Comment: @peterh There is a statement in the [PKCS_12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12#Normal_usage) under *Normal Usage* that states `The full PKCS #12 standard is very complex. It enables buckets of complex objects such as PKCS #8 structures, nested deeply. But in practice it is normally used to store just one private key and its associated certificate chain.`

Comment: @peterh And for the password, I couldn't find a source that states that it has to be the same. But I know that tools using/creating it will ignore/warn about it. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOGON.png) is what Java (11) shows.

Comment: @RobM a Wikipedia article is not an Internet standard. Even the actual RFC 7292 is marked as "Informational", not as a (proposed) standard.